# GoogleScript XmlService method setAttribute for adding "xml:lang"

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

How I can generate such XML tag in Googlescript via XmlService?

```
<display-name xml:lang="x-default">Adam</display-name>
```

I have used different variants `setAttribute` but nothing is works.

```
XmlService.createElement('display-name').setAttribute('lang', 'x-default'); 
// prefix `xml:` has not added

XmlService.createElement('display-name').setAttribute('lang', 'x-default', XmlService.getNamespace('someurl')); 
// fatal error: We're sorry, a server error occurred

XmlService.createElement('display-name').setAttribute('lang', 'x-default', XmlService.getNamespace('xml', 'someurl')); 
// fatal error: Invalid argument

// but in case fake namespace - OK
XmlService.createElement('display-name').setAttribute('lang', 'x-default', XmlService.getNamespace('qqq', 'someurl')); 
// <display-name xmlns:qqq="http://example.com" qqq:lang="x-default" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "xml:" namespace as defined [here](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace)

This is available in Google Apps Script by calling:

```
XmlService.getXmlNamespace()
```

So, you can achieve what you want with the following code:

```
XmlService.createElement('display-name')
      .setAttribute('lang', 'x-default', XmlService.getXmlNamespace())
      .setText('Adam');
```